# numpy concatenation along axis is not working with generated arrays

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, nan

when we concatenate along axis with 1d array and 2d array, we can produce concatenated arrays like this.

```
a = np.c_[np.array([10,12]),[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([2,3,4])]]

array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [12,  2,  3,  4]])
```

I am trying to do same thing with generated 2d nan array with given 1d array.Somehow concatenation is not working.I think issue with when generating the nan arrays.What is the reason for this?

```
tmp = np.array([280, 362, 236, 239, 336, 347, 238, 327, 369, 238, 324, 264, 280,
       284, 347, 265, 303, 276, 261, 274, 353, 260, 280, 240, 312, 239,
       314, 319, 238, 324, 322, 238, 226, 294, 280, 276, 306, 265, 203,
       292, 261, 265, 284, 260, 184, 294, 312, 226, 284, 319, 238, 281,
       322, 180, 284, 294, 253, 282, 306, 194, 282, 292, 246, 279, 284,
       205])

tmp2 = np.array([7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7,
       7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7,
       6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6])

nans = [ np.ones(i)*np.nan for i in tmp2]
concat = np.c_[tmp,nans]
```

output

```
array([[280, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       [362, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       [236, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       [239, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       [336, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       [347, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])],
       ....
```

expected output

```
array([[280,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [362,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [236,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [239,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
           ....
        ])
```

Comment: Clarify, what's not working?  Is the `output` desired or actual?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: not getting any error,I will update desired output.

Comment: @hpaulj I have updated the expected output.looks concatenation is not working as small example I have mentioned in the question,

Comment: @RajithThennakoon You cannot have non-rectangular arrays in numpy. If you insist on having variable length arrays within an array, your choices are array of arrays or array of lists or list of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code failed is that *Numpy* does not support "jagged"
arrays (with varying number of elements in each row).

You can add as many *NaN* columns as you wish (the same number in each row),
executing:

```
n = 5  # How many NaN columns to add
tmp = np.array([280, 362, 236, 239])
result = np.c_[tmp, np.full((tmp.size, n), np.nan)]
```

The result is:

```
array([[280.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [362.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [236.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [239.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this, if performance is not so important it will work fine.

```
output = []
for i, k in zip(tmp, tmp2):
       nans = np.ones(k) * np.nan
       output.append(np.concatenate([np.array([i]),nans]))

print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,yes its possible by using brute force method.I had to create custom function like this to do the rest of work.my dataset is quite large and it will hurt the performance for sure.

Comment: What kind of performance do you expect?  The fast numpy stuff is for multidimensional numeric arrays, not object dtype arrays of lists (or other arrays).  You might as well use lists.